# Make a vertical menu cascade horizontally

Tags: bootstrap-4, menu, width

I want to increase menu width when text is long and make it a waterfall menu. Currently when the text is long, the template adds dots like this: ...

Here is an example of what it does:

[image]

And here is an example of what I would like (the example is on the horinzontal menu, but I want the same principle on the vertical menu):

[image]

I tried to integrate the classes of the horizontal menu to that of the vertical menu, but the result was all crooked

This is the html code (condensed):

```
<body class="vertical-layout vertical-menu 3-columns   fixed-navbar" data-open="hover" data-menu="vertical-menu" data-col="3-columns">

    <nav class="header-navbar navbar-expand-md navbar navbar-with-menu fixed-top navbar-semi-light bg-gradient-x-grey-blue" style="background-color: #414042 !important">
        <div class="navbar-wrapper" style="background-color: #2e1846 !important">
            <div class="navbar-header" style="background-color: #2e1846 !important">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav flex-row">
                    <li class="nav-item mobile-menu d-md-none mr-auto"></li>
    [...]
/ul>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-container content">
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-mobile" style="/*padding-top:15px;*/">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav mr-auto float-left">
                        <li class="nav-item d-none d-md-block">
[...]
/li>
                    </ul>
    /div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

 <div class="main-menu menu-fixed menu-light menu-accordion menu-shadow expanded" data-scroll-to-active="true" style="touch-action: none; user-select: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
        <div class="main-menu-content">
<ul class="navigation navigation-main" id="main-menu-navigation" data-menu="menu-navigation">
                <li class=" navigation-header">
                    <i class=" feather icon-minus" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-original-title="General"></i>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" id="navbarDropdown">
                        <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
                        <span class="menu-title" data-i18n="Accueil">
                            @Lst.Where(x => x.ID == "278").FirstOrDefault().Text <!--Accueil-->
                        </span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="menu-content">

                        <li>

                            <a class="menu-item" href="/Home/Index" id="Accueil" data-i18n="Accueil">
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                @Lst.Where(x => x.ID == "278").FirstOrDefault().Text <!--Accueil-->
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="menu-item" href="#" data-i18n="Mes suivis">
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                @Lst.Where(x => x.ID == "1613").FirstOrDefault().Text <!--Mes suivis-->
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="menu-item" href="#" data-i18n="Notes des candidats">
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                @Html.Raw(Lst.Where(x => x.ID == "1614").FirstOrDefault().Text) <!--Notes des candidats-->
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve the problem try this code

NOTE - check the output with laptop/pc screen for better view

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <style>
        .navbar-nav li:hover>ul.dropdown-menu {
            display: block;
        }

        .dropdown-submenu {
            position: relative;
        }

        .dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
            top: 0;
            left: 100%;
            margin-top: -6px;
        }

        /* rotate caret on hover */
        .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover:after {
            text-decoration: underline;
            transform: rotate(-90deg);
        }
    </style>


    <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand pb-2" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown"
            aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                        data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Dropdown
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle"
                                href="http://google.com">Google</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu0</a></li>
                                <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Submenu
                                        1</a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Subsubmenu1</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Subsubmenu1</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Submenu
                                        2</a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Subsubmenu2</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Subsubmenu2</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I don't know if it was me who asked my question badly, but I want to have the same principle as the horizontal menu (2nd photo), but in my vertical menu (1st photo), the answer you gave me is a horizontal menu. I modified my question and added the html code (the actions would happen in the .main-menu class)